# How can I convert a Hugging Face Transformers ViTForImageClassification model to Tensorflow.js?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, tensorflow.js, pytorch-lightning

Is it possible to convert a Hugging Face Transformers (specifically a ViTForImageClassification) model to a Tensorflow.js model? My model is a finetune of `google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k` with about 60 labels. It was trained for 15 epochs with PyTorch Lightning using the GPU as an accelerator.

I have tried to convert it to a TFViTForImageClassification using `from_pt=True`, but when I converted it to TF.JS, it failed to load.